# Visual Studio 2017 PMC Add-Migrations Not Working, No Errors

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-migrations

I created my project and was able to add a few migrations and update the database accordingly using the PMC.

Today; however, I cannot seem to add-migrations at all.

Here's what happens:

```
PM> add-migration EventEntities
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\MyUserAccount\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
PM>
```

Notice, there are no errors.  It simply writes the "User profile is avail..." and after hanging for about 30 seconds acts like nothing ever happened and my migrations are not created...

**Why would add-migrations suddenly stop working?  How can I get some kind of error message to appear?**

I have tried several solutions, including:

- `$error[0].Exception.StackTrace` but it outputs nothing.
- `update-package -reinstall` in attempt to re-install all packages but it had no effect on the issue above.
- Running Visual Studio 2017 as an administrator but it had no effect on the issue above.

**Update:** After commenting out some code in my Startup.cs file and re-running the PMC add-migration command, I began to receive the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The convention invocations have reached the recursion limit. This is likely an issue in EF Core, please report it.
```

It looks like this is an issue caused by the way my new entities have been setup with regard to related entities and foreign keys.  I will work backwards to see if I can find the specific issue.

Comment: They are tracking a related bug: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9506

Comment: I found https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9265 which seemed to be a closer match to what I was experiencing.  Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have determined my issue was caused by the related entity relationship.  My solution was to specify the foreign keys like so:

```
public class Event
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EventId")]
    public virtual ICollection<EventHostAssociation> Hosts { get; set; }
}

public class EventHostAssociation
{
    public Guid EventId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ICollection<EventHostAssociation> EventHosts { get; set; }
}
```

And, finally, in my ApplicationDbContext.cs file, I specified my composite key:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<EventHostAssociation>().HasKey(c => new { c.EventId, c.UserId });
    }
```

The issue has been discussed here, also: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9265

Comment: I don't understand this usage, i.e. using a [ForeignKey] Attribute on a collection navigation property... does this have something to do with the fact that ApplicationUser is inherited from IdentityUser? (i.e. it doesn't find it's [Key] property?)

Comment: Sorry to reply a year later lol...  But, for posterity, there are several ways to describe a relationship in Entity Framework and using the [ForeignKey] attribute on the navigation property is one of them.  This method, and a couple of others are described in detail here: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 1):

EventHostAssociation table should have foreignkey reference of Event
you should add this line in EventHostAssociation table

```
[ForeignKey("EventAsso")
public int EventId {get;set;}
public virtual EventHostAssociation EventAsso{get;set:}
```